# How to initialize a forward-declared class in C++

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have two classes, `A` and `B`, which depend on each other:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    B* b;
    A() {
        b = new B();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A* a;
    B() = default;
};
```

This code will not compile because there is a circular dependency chain. However there is still an error even if I forward-declare the class `B` to resolve the circular dependency:

```
.code.tio.cpp:7:11: error: allocation of incomplete type 'B'
                b = new B();
                        ^
```

I believe this error is stating that I cannot initialize `B` because it is a forward-declared class, but I still need `A` and `B` to depend on each other, so how do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the problem, move the body of the `A()` constructor to somewhere after where the full `B` class is defined, like this:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    B* b;
    A();
};

class B {
public:
    A* a;
    B() = default;
};

A :: A() {
   b = new B();
}
```